# Change href location

Tags: html

I want to change the link of the href when I click the first paragraph. I tried setting a target but that doesn't seem to work.

```html
<a href="https://youtu.be/DM1sdIntawg" target="youtube">
  <p>Click to change the link to the video</p></a>

<a id="youtube" name="youtube" href="https://youtu.be/XphhA4djzko">
  <p>This is the changed link to the video</p></a>
```

Comment: You expected `target` to work because magic?  Did you not read the docs on what the target attribute does?

Comment: can you post more detail as to what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible without client-side javascript (although I'm not sure about the capabilities of HTML5)

Try this inline code...

```html
<a href="https://youtu.be/DM1sdIntawg" onclick="document.getElementById('youtube').href = this.href;return false;">
  <p>Click to change the link to the video</p></a>
    
<a id="youtube" name="youtube" href="https://youtu.be/XphhA4djzko">
  <p>This is the changed link to the video</p></a>
```

Or the same thing using a function...

```js
function changeLink(ctrl) {
  document.getElementById("youtube").href = ctrl.href;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://youtu.be/DM1sdIntawg" onclick="changeLink(this);return false;">
  <p>Click to change the link to the video</p></a>
    
<a id="youtube" name="youtube" href="https://youtu.be/XphhA4djzko">
  <p>This is the changed link to the video</p></a>
```